# How to use Artifactory maven with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, artifactory

I want to use Maven to store depended jars, and use it in Eclipse project.
To do so, I install Artifactory and upload my jars to libs-release-local repo.
After that I [generate settings.xml](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Maven#WorkingwithMaven-AutomaticallyGeneratingSettings) and replace it in my local .m2 folder.
I install Eclipse Luna with integrated Maven support, set my libs-release-local repo in Window - Preferences - Maven - Archetypes.
After that I create new Maven poject and try to add depended jars (Right click on poject - Maven - Add Dependency), but can't find any of my jars.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause.
By default, the Artifactory does not create the Maven Indexes
This page explains how to enable the indexing:
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Exposing+Maven+Indexes